# Restrict choices in a ManyToManyField declaration

Tags: django, django-models

I have stripped my code to the relevant parts.

In my model definitions, I have 3 classes that are relevent here : **Project**, **Employee**, **Desk**.

Each **Desk** is linked to a **Project** via a **ForeignKey**.
In my definition of the **Desk** class I have the following line :

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Now, each **Employee** is also related to a **Project** in the exact same way.

Here comes my problem :

I am trying to link each Desk to different employees, so I have added the line :

```
employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, null=True, blank=True)
```

But I dont want EVERY **Employee** to be linkable to a given **Desk**.
I want to be able a link a **Desk** to as many as I want of the **Employee** who are linked to the same **Project**.

I have tried to modify my line to the following :

```
employee = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, null=True, blank=True, limit_choices_to={'project': project})
```

But I get the following error :

```
Error when calling the metaclass bases
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ForeignKey'
```

I have tried changing my line to :

```
limit_choices_to={'project': project.id}

limit_choices_to={'project': project.pk}

limit_choices_to={'project': self.project}

limit_choices_to={'project': self.project.pk}
```

And many other variations but none have given any result...

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `queryset` in your form instead of `limit_choices_to` in your model, and pass `project_id` to your form or loading it from form instance (`form.instance.project`):

```
class YourFormForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, project_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourFormForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
             self.fields['employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(project_id=self.instance.project_id)
```

Comment: Actually I have two different forms. One for Desk creation where the field for Employee is hidden and empty, and one for Desk editing, where the project is always already existing. I guess that solves one problem here. However, if the query set is only updated on first load I might end up having contradictions since other users might update the list in between two different loads. Is it possible to update the queryset every time I call the form?

Comment: What I mean is, what if I remove the "if 'initial' in kwargs" ? Will it still work ?

Comment: Yes you can remove it, `__init__` method is called every form instantiation.

Comment: Ok I will use your solution since it works perfectly and seems to fit all my requirements ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually, I got an issue with your solution. In the select box, I only get the Employees I wanted, which is perfect. However, upon validating my changes I get an error message telling me I need to make a valid choice and that N isn't a valid value. (N being the id of the selected Employee).

Comment: OK. I have finally managed to make it work. Your solution was clearly on the right path. However, even without the "if 'initial' in kwargs", when the form was loaded again (for validation checks for example) the queryset was lost. So instead if putting it in the init method, I added the queryset in the views.py right after calling any instance of the form. Now it's all good ;) Thanks again !